# Can I scrape data from web pages when the data comes from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase my question but I'll give it my best shot.

If I load up a webpage, in the HTML it executes a JavaScript file.  And if I view the page source I can see the source of that JavaScript (though it's not very well formatted and hard to understand).

Is there a way to run the JavaScript from e.g. Python code, without going through the browser?  i.e if I wanted to access a particular function in that JavaScript, is there a clean way to call just that from a Python script, and read the results?

For example... a webpage displays a number that I want access to.  It's not in the page source because it's a result from a JavaScript call.  Is there a way to call that JavaScript from Python?

Comment: Are you running in the context of the browser? Aka open up the JS console and type the method name.

Comment: I think you're just looking for the console...

Comment: You can install NodeJS and run Javascript without a browser.

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself clearly enough.  I can run the console but if I wanted to access it from another language like python is there a way to do that?  I've edited the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: are you trying to control an already opened page with python? and send commands to it?

Comment: The page doesn't necessarily have to be open (in a browser or in general).  I just need the results of one of the javascript calls in that page upon its opening.  And I need access to it from another language like python

Comment: you would have to execute the JS in python, which i'd like to see if yoy find a way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scrape a page with javascript in it you've got at least two options:

- Use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to load the page and get the node value you're interested in
- Use [python-spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey) to leverage the javascript right from your python script and get the value you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question isn't very clear. I'm guessing that you are trying to access the javascript console.

In Google Chrome:

- Press F12
- Go to the 'console' tab

In Mozilla Firefox with Firebug installed:

- Open Firebug
- Go to the 'console' tab

From the console you can execute javascript query's (calling functions, accessing variables etc.).

I hope this answered your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Obfuscate js code

You can always de-obfuscate them

There are lots of tools availaible

Here is a addon of mozilla 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/

and an online tool
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: In fact chrome debugger console has 'pretty-print' option to make it easier to read